# "As per picture below" or "as per the picture below"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage, expression-choice

Suppose you are sending an email which includes some details in a picture below where you are writing.

Is it correct to say

> *As per picture below*, the meeting is in (...)

Or is it better/more correct to say

> *As per the picture below*, the meeting is in (...)

Google returns [~200k results for the former sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20per%20picture%20below%22) and just [~80k for the latter](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20per%20the%20picture%20below%22), but then again, [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com) marks the former case as incorrect, suggesting to add "*the*".

Is one of the two preferable over the other?

Comment: The latter is grammatical (if almost ridiculously formal; 'shown in' is idiomatic English); the former is an acceptable use of 'headlinese' in informal contexts (though 'as shown in picture below' perhaps mismatches registers).

Comment: This has been beaten to death on this site. See previous related posts and read up on "zero-article." Good Luck. Grammarly cannot be faulted for everything.

Comment: I’d avoid the Latin “per” in this case (and many others) and use a more natural English preposition.  I think you would be able to express your idea using “in” or “shown in”, although quite why you have a picture of a meeting is unclear to me.

Comment: @Kris Really, there have been posts on the preposition *per* and its ability to take either bare NPs or normal ones depending on the meaning? Are there really?

Comment: @Araucaria It's nothing special about *per*, why complicate and confound?

Comment: @Kris Five times per minute of five times per the minute? Tenty miles per the hour? I don't think so. Conversely, as per question above, sorry, I meant *the* question above. Oh, hold on. where was I ... (See what I did there?)

Comment: @Araucaria More confusion. Relax!